# Define a class Calculator that can satisfy the following code. var cal = new Calculator(); cal.add(3, 5);// 8 cal.add([3, 5]);// 8

Tags: javascript

Define a class Calculator that can satisfy the following code.

```
var cal = new Calculator(); cal.add(3, 5);// 8 cal.add([3, 5]);// 8
```

How about my code?

```
function Calculator(){
   this.p1=p1;
   this.p2=p2;
   this.add =function(){
    return this.p1+this.p2;   
    }
}

var cal = new Calculator();
console.log(cal.add(3, 5));
```

It cannot work

Comment: reference error p1 is not defined. You should see this message in your console.

Comment: What is p1 and p2? Also, what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement some parameter to the methode `add`.

```js
function Calculator(){
    this.add = function (p1, p2) {
        return p1 + p2;   
    }
}

var cal = new Calculator();
console.log(cal.add(3, 5));
```

Or use a method for input, a stack and a method for Addition.

```js
function Calculator() {
    this.stack = [];
}

Calculator.prototype.input = function (value) {
    this.stack.push(value);
}

Calculator.prototype.add = function () {
    var value = this.stack.pop() + this.stack.pop();
    this.stack.push(value);
    return value;
}

var cal = new Calculator;
cal.input(3);
cal.input(5);
console.log(cal.add());
```

Comment: Maybe better to use `Calculator.prototype.add`

Answer (score 0):

Spot the difference:

```
console.log(cal.add(3, 5));
                    ^--^---- two arguments

function Calculator(){
                    ^---zero arguments expected

this.add =function(){
                   ^--- zero arguments, again...
```

which means `p1` and `p2` are undefined. If you'd done ANY kind of basic debugging, like checking your browser's debug console, you'd have been told about this.

Perhaps if you had

```
function Calculator(p1, p2) {
```

or similar...

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters for p1, p2, and an optional array in the "add" method.  You can use the "arguments" object to check if two numbers were passed in or an array.  I'm sure there is a much better way to do this, but not sure.
In your Calculator function do this:

```
function Calculator() { 
    this.p1;
    this.p2;
    this.add = function(p1, p2, arr) { 
        var args = arguments;
        if(args.length == 2){
       this.p1 = p1; 
          this.p2 = p2; 
        }else{
           this.p1 = args[0][0];
           this.p2 = args[0][1];
        }
        console.log(this.p1 + this.p2);
        return this.p1 + this.p2;
    } 
}; 

var cal = new Calculator;
cal.add(5, 4);  \\logs 9
cal.add([5, 4]);. \\logs 9
```

Comment: This at least let's you pass on numbers or an Array of numbers to the function and p1, p2 is updated with current values.